# Maven test, Jenkins Test Suite failure java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError -

Tags: firefox, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, maven-2

I am attempting to run my tests through Maven however I am getting an error during the build process. I've tried for the last 2 days to resolve this but now running out of ideas. I have made sure my POM has the correct dependencies and that the tests work outside of Jenkins.

OS - Windows Server 2012 R2
Browser - firefox 50.1.0
Selenium Driver - 3.0.1

Jenkins Error Log

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Running TestSuite
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified

09:48:46.025 [main] INFO  - START com.Ceridian.tests.HB01.CD01
09:48:46.119 [main] WARN  - SKIP  com.Ceridian.tests.HB01.CD01
09:48:46.119 [main] ERROR - Unable to take screenshot - java.lang.NullPointerException
09:48:46.135 [main] INFO  - START com.Ceridian.tests.HB01.CD02
09:48:46.150 [main] WARN  - SKIP  com.Ceridian.tests.HB01.CD02
09:48:46.150 [main] ERROR - Unable to take screenshot - java.lang.NullPointerException
Tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 2.688 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
configureBrowserBeforeTest(com.Ceridian.tests.HB01)  Time elapsed: 2 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException

configureBrowserBeforeTest(com.Ceridian.tests.HB01)  Time elapsed: 0.093 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException

Results :

Failed tests: 
com.Ceridian.tests.HB01.configureBrowserBeforeTest(com.Ceridian.tests.HB01)
  Run 1: HB01>BaseTest.configureBrowserBeforeTest:102 » NoClassDefFound org/openqa/sele...
  Run 2: HB01>BaseTest.configureBrowserBeforeTest:102 » NoClassDefFound org/openqa/sele...
```

Jenkins Build Failure

```
[JENKINS] Recording test results

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.354 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-06T09:48:52+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/442M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project Frameworkium: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\FirstAttempt\workspace\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project Frameworkium: There are test failures.
```

POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.frameworkium</groupId>
    <artifactId>Frameworkium</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>2.0.5</version>

    <name>Frameworkium</name>
    <description>
        A template designed to get up and running quickly with Selenium and Appium.
    </description>
    <url/>
    <inceptionYear/>
    <organization/>
    <licenses/>

    <developers/>
    <contributors/>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <modules/>

    <scm/>
    <issueManagement/>
    <ciManagement/>
    <distributionManagement/>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <env.config>local</env.config>
        <threads>1</threads>
        <groups/>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.Frameworkium</groupId>
            <artifactId>frameworkium-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>
                    src/main/resources
                </directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tests</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <screenshotDirectory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/screenshots
                                </screenshotDirectory>
                                <allure.issues.tracker.pattern>
                                    /browse/%s
                                </allure.issues.tracker.pattern>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Tests*.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                                <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <groups>${groups}</groups>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                            </argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The Jenkins Logs seem to mention my @BeforeMethod as a possible reason for failure so I'll just include that here

```
@BeforeMethod(
    alwaysRun = true
)
public static void configureBrowserBeforeTest(Method testMethod) {
    try {
        ((Driver)driver.get()).resetBrowser();
        wait.set(newDefaultWait());
        userAgent = determineUserAgent();
        initialiseNewScreenshotCapture(testMethod);
    } catch (Exception var2) {
        logger.error("Failed to configure browser.", var2);
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to configure browser.", var2);
    }
}
```

I've included my configuration screen of the build.
[image: Configuration screen of build]

Apologies if I've missed something out.

Adding dependencies

[image]

Comment: Looks like an artifact in org.openqa is missing.  Check your Maven dependency tree to make sure it's brought you by one of your dependencies.  I would mark all those Selenium dependencies as test scope.  Also check the package to make sure that they are present.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry to ask some basic questions  I'm new to setting up a CI environment. The Maven Dependency tree is that the maven plugin? How do you check that through Jenkins? If my POM is pulling the dependencies OK outside of Jenkins why is it that it could be missing with Jenkins? You mention checking the package to make sure they are present, would be able to elaborate on where to check? I'm thinking you mean somewhere in the Jenkins folder on my C:? Appreciate the assistance :)

Comment: No check things outside of Jenkins. Look at the package.  I use IntelliJ to check the dependency tree

Comment: @duffymo ah ok I've included in the original question.

Comment: @duffymo thanks for your help, I had to use a newer version of one of the repositories and it seemed to work. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

So it is also on 3.0.1 and the error went away. Thanks to @duffymo for the help.